# Copy part of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, array

I have an array and must fill another one.

Depending of a boolean I copy first or second element and the rest must be as is...

Currently I do it like this (`data` has the desired info):

```
const newArray = [];
newArray[0] = theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1];
for (let i = 2; i < data.length; i += 1) {
  newArray[i - 1] = data[i];
}
```

I've tried with shift and slice but no success...

¿how can I beautify this snippet?

Comment: Hey @Joc, I am posting this comment regarding this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403946/whatsapp-button-sharing-different-url-than-actual/42626674?noredirect=1#comment72461670_42626674   in Stackoverflow. Since I am in a 6 day suspension, I can't inreact with you there

Comment: @SagarV tell me, you have some idea what's going on?

Comment: tell me your exact requirement whether you want to add the page url or any other url with some text?

Comment: @Sagar Yes, I want to share another ULR, concretely the `actual URL+"#name"` as stated in comments. Read question and comments carefully, all is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track trying `slice`. Here's an example of using it with no loops required.

**Initialisation**

You could initialise `newArray` with an element directly in the declaration, removing the need for `newArray[0] = ...`:

`const newArray = [theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1]];`

**Pushing all other elements from data to newArray:**

You could use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get all other elements: `data.slice(2)`.

Using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const newArray = [theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1]];
newArray.push(...data.slice(2));

// or, one liner:
const newArray = [theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1], ...data.slice(2)];
```

Using [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const newArray = [theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1]].concat(data.slice(2));
```

Using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
const newArray = [theBoolean ? data[0] : data[1]];
[].push.apply(newArray, data.slice(2));
```

Comment: It should be noted that stack size is limited so you'll need to check if the number of elements for `push.apply` is less than some safe value e.g. 1024, otherwise use `concat`.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think your current technique could be improved by using [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) rather than array indices when inserting.

However another couple of options come to mind:

1. Using `Array.filter` to remove the unwanted item

   ```
   const newArray = data.filter(function (_, index) {
       return theBoolean? index !== 1 : index !== 0;
   });
   ```
2. To delete the unwanted item with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) if you do not mind mutating the source array.

> array.splice(start, deleteCount)
>
> **start**
>
> Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater
>   than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the
>   length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from
>   the end of the array.
>
> **deleteCount** Optional
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If
>   deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should
>   specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the
>   number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of
>   the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.

```
data.splice(theBoolean? 1 : 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
const newArray = data.slice(1);
if (theBoolean) newArray[0] = data[0];
```

Comment: -1 for no explanation at all.